# Could I get [variable name, value] table from javascript code using python?

Tags: javascript, python, lexer

I have a JavaScript file called `index.js`.
I'm developing a tool, written in Python, that it navigates JavaScript code statically to check if a certain API is defined or not.
In order to develop it, I need a data structure (table) which stores 
`[variable, value]`.

Here is the example of JavaScript code.

```
var a = "hello";
var b = "hi";

a = "world";
var c= certainAPI.method(parameter_1, parameter_2);
```

After using a tool, here is the table that I want to get.

```
---------------------------------------------------------
variable   |  value
---------------------------------------------------------
a          | "world"
---------------------------------------------------------
b          | "hi"
---------------------------------------------------------
c          | certainAPI.method(parameter_1, parameter_2)
---------------------------------------------------------
```

Are there any tools or modules that navigate JavaScript code and make such a table automatically? The structure type of table doesn't matter. `list`, `dict`... all types are fine. I just want to get (var, value) matching set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a popular parser for JavaScript written in JavaScript. Its called [Esprima](http://esprima.org)

It helps you obtain the full syntax tree.

I found a port of it in Python. It is not popular, but you can check it out.

[github.com/int3/pyesprima](https://github.com/int3/pyesprima)